# Format SQL in YAML CI pipeline

Tags: sql, azure-devops, yaml, continuous-integration

I'm building a database solution using a YAML Continuous Integration pipeline and want to format the SQL scripts so that they're consistent.

i.e. so that:

```
INSERT INTO tblTest (t1, 
                     t2, 
                     t3)
VALUES (@t1, 
        @t2, 
        @t3)
```

becomes:

```
INSERT INTO tblTest (t1, t2, t3)
VALUES (@t1, @t2, @t3)
```

Is there a YAML task that can do this? I'm not worried about the format, more concerned with the consistency between commits.

Ideally this would be a task that could be integrated into a YAML CI Pipe Line

```
steps:
- task: (Format task goes here)

- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **/*.sln'
  inputs:
    configuration: Release
    msbuildArguments: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true'
    maximumCpuCount: true

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'
    Contents: '**\bin\**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Output'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    ArtifactName: Output
```

Comment: Reformatting the .sql files within the pipeline is perhaps not the best way to go about this. Instead, how about imposing formatting standards on the .sql files before they are committee to the repository?

Comment: Hi Hunch, any update on this question, have you checked the answer, does it answered your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No built-in feature for your requirements.

I Write a YAML file with python script, it can meet your requirement:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      import re

      #read sql script from file
      def read_sql(file):
          with open(file, 'r') as f:
              sql = f.read()
          return sql

      #write sql script to file
      def write_sql(file, sql):
          with open(file, 'w') as f:
              f.write(sql)
          return

      #format every sql script step to one line
      def format_sql(sql):
          sql = re.sub(r'\n\s*', ' ', sql)
          sql = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', sql)
          return sql

      #split string via 'operator'
      def split_select(sql, operator):
          sql = sql.split(operator)
          # print(sql)
          return sql


      sql = read_sql('test.sql')
      # print(sql)
      sql = format_sql(sql)
      # print(sql)
      enums = split_select(sql,'INSERT')
      enums2 = []
      enumss2 = []
      for i in enums:
          # print(i)
          enums.index(i)
          if enums.index(i) == 0:
              print('first')
          else:
              #add i to array
              enums2.append("INSERT"+i)
      print("========================================================")
      for i in enums2:
          print(i)
          enumss = split_select(i,'VALUES')
          print(enumss)
          for j in enumss:
              if enumss.index(j) == 0:
                 enumss2.append(j)
              else:
                 enumss2.append('VALUES'+j)
      print("========================================================")
      for i in enumss2:
          print(i)


      # write_sql('test.sql', sql)
```

Successfully on my side:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYQF6.png)

If you want to format other operators, you can add more, the logic is similar.